# Fastest Algorithm for Distance Transform

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, distance-metrics

I am looking for the fastest available algorithm for distance transform.

According to [Image Processing Learning Resources - HIPR 2 (HYPERMEDIA IMAGE PROCESSING REFERENCE) - Morphology - Distance Transform](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/distance.htm):

> The distance transform can be calculated much more efficiently using
> clever algorithms in only two passes (e.g. Rosenfeld and Pfaltz
> 1968).

Searching around, I found: "Rosenfeld, A and Pfaltz, J L. 1968. Distance Functions on Digital Pictures. Pattern Recognition, 1, 33-61."

But I believe we should have a better and faster algorithm than the one in 1968 already? In fact, I could not find the source from 1968, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for getting this thread up again, but I'm trying to implement the GDT as well, but using Python. def of_column(dataInput): output = zeros(dataInput.shape) n = len(dataInput) k = 0 v = zeros((n,)) z = zeros((n + 1,)) v[0] = 0 z[0] = -inf z[1] = +inf s = 0 for q in range(1, n): while True: s = (((dataInput[q] + q * q) - (dataInput[v[k]] + v[k] * v[k])) / (2.0 * q - 2.0 * v[k])) if s <= z[k]: k -= 1 else: break k += 1 v[k] = q z[k] = s z[k + 1] = +inf k = 0 for q in range(n): while z[k + 1] < q: k += 1 output[q] = ((q - v[k]) * (q - v[k]) + dataInput[v[k]]) return output However when offeri

Comment: Please ask a new question. Don't post questions as answers.

Comment: Welcome to Signal Processing SE. You can ask a question using the "Ask Question" in top right corner.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pedro F. Felzenszwalb and Daniel P. Huttenlocher have published their implementation for the [distance transform](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Epff/dt/) [[archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230207044011/http://cs.brown.edu/people/pfelzens/dt/)]. You cannot use it for volumetric images, but maybe you can extend it to support 3d data. I have only used it as a black box.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this is implemented in OpenCV?

Comment: Yes, for certain values of `maskSize` and `distanceType`. See: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-distancetransform

Comment: is there any implementations for volumetric images (e.g., kinect depth image) till now?

Answer (score 11):

This paper discusses all of the modern exact distance transforms:

"2D Euclidean distance transforms: a comparative survey", ACM Computing Surveys, Vol 40, Issue 1, Feb 2008
http://www.lems.brown.edu/~rfabbri/stuff/fabbri-EDT-survey-ACMCSurvFeb2008.pdf

The paper cites the technique from Meijster, et. al. as the fastest general purpose, exact transform. This technique is detailed here:

"A General Algorithm for Computing Distance Transforms in Linear Time", A. Meijster, J. B. T. M. Roerdink and W. H. Hesselink.
http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/S62.12/docs/Meijster_distance.pdf

The Meijster algorithm is used in my open source effects library:
https://github.com/vinniefalco/LayerEffects

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: It would be useful to know where in your library can we find the particular code.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a C# code for 1D squared euclidean distance transform according to the [Felzenszwald & Huttenlocher's paper](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~pff/dt/):

```
private static void DistanceTransform(double[] dataInput, ref double[] dataOutput)
{
    int n = dataInput.Length;

    int k = 0;
    int[] v = new int[n];
    double[] z = new double[n + 1];

    v[0] = 0;
    z[0] = Double.NegativeInfinity;
    z[1] = Double.PositiveInfinity;

    double s;

    for (int q = 1; q < n; q++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            s = (((dataInput[q] + q * q) - (dataInput[v[k]] + v[k] * v[k])) / (2.0 * q - 2.0 * v[k]));

            if (s <= z[k])
            {
                k--;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        k++;

        v[k] = q;
        z[k] = s;
        z[k + 1] = Double.PositiveInfinity;
    }

    k = 0;

    for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
    {
        while (z[k + 1] < q)
        {
            k++;
        }

        dataOutput[q] = ((q - v[k]) * (q - v[k]) + dataInput[v[k]]);
    }
}
```

This can be readily used for binary and grayscale images by applying it first on image columns and then rows (or vice versa, of course).

The transform is indeed very fast.

Here are the source and output images:

[image]

[image]

The black pixels have value 0 and the white have some large value (have to be larger than largest possible squared distance in the images but not infinity) so that the transform returns distance from the black pixels and the white ones are ommited.

To get true euclidean distance transform, simply take a square root of each pixel from the output image.

Comment: Interesting. What is a common use of the distance transform, Libor?

Comment: I think the common uses are in finding paths, segmentation, geometrical measurements (center of mass) and effects (bevel effect).
I needed distance transform for panoramic image stitching - to find a geometrically optimal blending mask. This involved running distance transform on each image, and then computing blending mask from the weights.

Comment: The distance transform can be used in matching [edge] images, one technique being "chamfer matching"(http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~mingyliu/papers/liu_cvpr2010.pdf). The DT can also be used to find medial axis (skeleton) and to perform other tasks such as Libor mentioned.

Comment: @Libor How should the input array ( double[] ) be filled, and subsequently called? Is it an array of normalized values between 0 and 1, where 0 is black and 1 is white? Or is it an array of values between 0 and double.MaxValue? Please consider including an example where you populate the input array and call the method.